# MySQL monthly sums

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `transactions` like this

| date | amount |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-02-26 | 1000 |
| 2020-02-26 | 1500 |
| 2021-01-11 | 200 |

I want to select the sum of all transactions per month. The result should look something like...

| month | sum |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-02 | 2500 |
| 2021-01 | 200 |

This is what I've got so far

```sql
select sum(amount) sum, MONTH(date) month from transactions group by month;
```

However this groups by month ignoring year (the values returned for month are single integers). I need to group by each individual month (return a different row for Jan 2020 vs Jan 2021)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is one way:

```
select sum(amount) sum, extract(YEAR_MONTH FROM `date`)  month 
from transactions 
group by month;
```